# Execute multiple batch files c#

Tags: c#

I hope that you can help me. When I want to execute those .bat files, I can see that the files are executed but I can get only the first one, the second one or the others I can't get them, I have no problem with my batch files, I've tried to executed them one by one and it works.

```
 string str_Path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\execute.bat";
 string str_PathN= Server.MapPath(".") +"\\executeN.bat";
 string str_PathHD = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\executeHD.bat";
 string str_PathFHD = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\executeFHD.bat";

 ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(str_Path);
 processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 Process batchProcess = new Process();
 batchProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
 batchProcess.Start();
 Thread.Sleep(3000);

 ProcessStartInfo hd = new ProcessStartInfo(str_PathHD);
 hd.UseShellExecute = false;
 Process batchProcessHD = new Process();
 batchProcessHD.StartInfo = processInfo;
 batchProcessHD.Start();
 Thread.Sleep(3000);
 ...
```

Comment: You could create a single batch file that executes all the rest of them and just run that one? Might be less work.

Comment: What do you mean by `i can't get them`? Shouldn't `batchProcessHD.StartInfo = processInfo` be assigned `hd` instead?

Comment: @Duane Looks like that's the answer - why not post it as such? The danger of "copy and paste" programming.

Comment: I assume you are not trying to run bat file on the client, from a server decision, isn't it ?

Comment: no i'm running it in server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you

```
public static void runBatch( string path, int sleepTime = 3000 )
{
   ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo( path );

   psi.UseShellExecute = false;

   Process proc = new Process();
   proc.StartInfo = psi;

   proc.Start();
   Thread.Sleep( sleepTime );
}


main()
{
    runBatch(Server.MapPath(".") + "\\execute.bat");
    runBatch(Server.MapPath(".") +"\\executeN.bat");
...
}
```

Or a better version of runBatch:

```
public static void runBatch( string path )
{
   ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo( path );

   psi.UseShellExecute = false;

   Process proc = new Process();
   proc.StartInfo = psi;

   proc.Start();
   proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: have you tried writing a log from your cmd's? are they executed?

Comment: also, check the return value of Process.Start.. did it return true?

Comment: also check the ExitCode after WaitForExit

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify that code by using:

```
 public void ExecuteBatFiles(List<string> path, int time)
    {
        foreach(string location in path)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(location);
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process batchProcess = new Process();
            batchProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
            batchProcess.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(time);
        }
    }
```

If you just want to set the off one after the other. But it looks like `batchProcessHD.StartInfo = processInfo` should be assigned `hd` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're clearly very new to C#, but with limited understanding of your predicament, here's another way to do it.

Notice how all answers have avoided repeating the same block of setup code for the process.

Where you've copy and pasted you've run into the problem of not making all the edits needed and have introduced a bug which needs to be picked out by a keen eye.

Programmers strive to only write code once, to avoid the problem above and so if that code is found to be bugged and fixed later, fixing it once solves it across the entire app. Obviously it saves time to not have to write the same thing over and over, too.

The principle is called DRY and you can read more about it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

```
    private static void Run()
    {
        var processes = CreateBatchOfProcesses("execute.bat", "executeN.bat", "executeHD.bat", "executeFHD.bat");
        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();

            // Do other stuff with the process.
        }
    }

    private static List<Process> CreateBatchOfProcesses(params string[] paths)
    {
        var batch = new List<Process>(paths.Length);

        foreach (string path in paths)
        {
            string mappedPath = Server.MapPath(String.Concat(".\\", path));
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(mappedPath);
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = info;

            batch.Add(process);
        }

        return batch;
    }
```